# If gcd of two positive integers is 2 then both integers are even

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

The statement feels very obvious when you think about it, but I’m very stuck trying to prove it.

I first tried to prove it by contradiction but I didn’t get anywhere by doing that. I’ve been told that the best way to do it is to just use an example.

Surely there must be a better way of proving it mathematically? I just can’t seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: What is the definition of "evenness"? If it is being a multiple of $2$, then having $2$ as a 'divisor' proves it

Comment: $\text{GCD}(x,y)=d$ means that $x=dp;\;y=dq$ for some integer $p,q$. Now if you substitute $d=2$ you have your proof

Comment: $\gcd$ stands for "greatest common **divisor**".

Answer (score 1):

Observation: $gcd(a,b)|a$

This is a direct consequence of the fact that the gcd is a divisor of $a$. Therefore if the gcd is $2$, then $2|a$ so $a$ is even. Similarly, $b$ is even.

The reverse isn’t true. $4$ and $8$ are even but their $gcd$ is $4$, not $2$. However, there’s a simple way to patch the theorem to make it an if and only if. Do you see what it is?

Comment: Two positive even integers have a gcd of 2 if and only if the difference of the two integers is 2?

Comment: @Thestrugglingstudent That's a good observation, though it's not quite always true. $gcd(2,2)=gcd(-6,2)=2$, but in both cases the difference isn't 2. I was thinking that two numbers are both even if their gcd *is a multiple of* $2$.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you very much!